# Passing elements from an array to a linked list

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, linked-list

I was trying to make an algorithm that takes some elements into a Linked List and after it passes those elements into an array using Bubble Sort to sort the elements. I sorted those elements but now I'm not able to pass the elements from the array to the Linked List again.

I used the method `passIntoArray(Node head, int arr[])` to take the elements from the Linked List and pass into the array. The method `count(Node head)` is used to check how many elements there were in the Linked List(Currently being used as index of the array). Could anyone help me?

```
package LinkedList; 

public class LinkedListSorting {

    private static int count(Node head) {
        if (head == null) return 0;
        Node current = head;
        int count = 0;

        while(current != null) {
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        } return count;
    }

    private static void passIntoArray(Node head, int arr[]) {
        if (head == null) return;
        Node current = head;
        int i = 0;

        while(current != null) {
            arr[i] = current.data;
            i++;
            current = current.next;
        } 

        int length = count(head);

        for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<length; j++) {
                if(arr[i]>arr[j]) {
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }


    //FROM THE ARRAY TO THE LL



    private static void display(Node head) {
        if (head == null) return;
        Node current = head;

        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data + " --> ");
            current = current.next;
        } System.out.println(current);
    }

    private static class Node{
        private int data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node head = new Node(5);
        Node first = new Node(2);
        Node second = new Node(3);
        Node third = new Node(4);
        Node fourth = new Node(1);

        head.next = first;
        first.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        third.next = fourth;

        display(head);

        System.out.println();

        int arr[] = new int[count(head)];

        passIntoArray(head, arr);

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not clear the list and add the items from the array into the empty list?

Comment: Actually when I passed the elements from the linkedlist into the array, I tried to printout the LL and it was empty. I wanted to pass the array elements into the LL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to sort the elements of the linked list
It would be better if you sort them in the linked list itself.

```
public class Main {

    private static int count(Node head) {
        if (head == null) return 0;
        Node current = head;
        int count = 0;

        while(current != null) {
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        } return count;
    }

    private static void sortLL(Node head) {
        if (head == null) return;
        Node current = head;
        Node i,j;

        int length = count(head);

        for(i=head; i!=null; i=i.next) {
            for(j=i.next; j!=null; j=j.next) {
                if(i.data>j.data) {
                    int temp = i.data;
                    i.data = j.data;
                    j.data = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void display(Node head) {
        if (head == null) return;
        Node current = head;

        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data + " --> ");
            current = current.next;
        } System.out.println(current);
    }

    private static class Node{
        private int data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node head = new Node(5);
        Node first = new Node(2);
        Node second = new Node(3);
        Node third = new Node(4);
        Node fourth = new Node(1);

        head.next = first;
        first.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        third.next = fourth;

        sortLL(head);
        display(head);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for answering! I'm a beginner so I had no idea on how to sort the elements directly in the linked list. Thank you very much :D

Comment: I think count method is useless now cause i used it as the index of the array

Comment: My pleasure feel free to ask more